# How do I visualize grouped data from a dataframe using Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, visualization

After grouping two columns of data in my dataframe, I obtained a small table of integers whose image I've attached below.

[Please click here for the image of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLNtU.png)

This was the code used for grouping:

```
count = x_train.groupby(['bool_loc', 'target']).size()
```

I am trying to visualize this data (type int64) using python and thought that maybe a histogram with two categories 0 and 1 (for column 'bool_loc') and each category having two bars (for column 'target') with their heights representing frequency would be a good way to do so. I tried like this:

```
# create figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# plot histogram
ax.hist(count)
# set title and labels
ax.set_title('Relation Between Location Data Presence and Disaster Tweets')
ax.set_xlabel('Location Data Presence')
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency of Tweets')
```

The histogram I obtained:

[Image of obtained histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bteWs.png)

It seems that the frequency data has been plotted along the x-axis (it should be on the y-axis) instead of the data in 'bool_loc'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to visualize histograms based on the shape of your dataframe. Here is the result:
[2 histograms with 2 bins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OClWH.png)

I'm not sure if this complies with your data input, as I simply made similar dataframe to the one in your post. Probably you have it done differently.

The code is below:

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# make dataframe
arrays = [[0, 0, 1, 1],
          [0, 1, 0, 1]]
data = [1458, 1075, 2884, 2196] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=arrays, columns=['frequency'])

# get data from DF series
y1 = df.loc[0,'frequency'].to_list()
y2 = df.loc[1,'frequency'].to_list()

# get data arrays
arr1 = [0] * y1[0] + [1] * y1[1]
arr2 = [0] * y2[0] + [1] * y2[1]

# set matplotlib plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# plot histogram
num_bins = 2
ax.hist([arr1, arr2], num_bins, density=False, label=['bool_loc 0', 'bool_loc 1'])
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your code created the exact histogram I wanted to create. However there is one small error which I found and corrected: the numbers 1075 and 2884 should be switched in the data list to get the correct representation in the graph. I have one more question - is there a way to remove the numbering in the x axis and replace it with labels for each pair?

Comment: You can explicitely specify the ticks labels on the axes with `ax.set_xticklabels()`. [link](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html) . Very quick and very ugly workaround for your particulat case: `ax.set_xticklabels(('', '0', '1', '0', '1'))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
print (data.target.value_counts(normalize=True).plot(kind='bar'))
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for your reply. I did try creating the graph myself and have edited the question to include the code I used. I implemented your code as 

print(count.value_counts(normalize=True).plot(kind='bar'))

In this case however, the four frequency's are plotted as four separate bars in the graph, which isn't what I wanted.